# Linux set root password on etc/shadow file

Tags: regex, linux, sed, passwords, root

I'm building a ram filesystem, and I generated a "/" directory. I would like to set a default root password on the generated "etc/shadow" file.
The actual file is:

```
root:*:15980:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:15980:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:15980:0:99999:7:::
adm:*:15980:0:99999:7:::
...
.....
```

I would like to replace "root:*:" with "root:Hashedpassword:", I know it is very easy to replace "*" with the "HASHEDPASSWORD", But it should by done using the pattern "root:anything:", and this also should not be difficult, even-though I would like to ask about it here coz it may be useful for others.

For example:

the password I want to set is "centos"

The salt is "xyz"

I get the hashed pass:

```
pass=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz centos)
```

Then I would like te replace "anything" in "root:anything:" with "root:Hashedpassword:" with "sed" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with GNU sed like

```
sed -i -e "s/^root:[^:]\+:/root:$pass:/" etc/shadow
```

if `$pass` might have `/` characters in it you can use a different separator, like `,` if that won't be there.  You can do that like:

```
sed -i -e  "s,^root:[^:]\+:,root:$pass:," etc/shadow
```

if you do not have GNU sed you may not have `-i` or it may require an argument.

You could also use `awk` to do this:

```
awk -F: "BEGIN {OFS=FS;} \$1 == \"root\" {\$2=\"$pass\"} 1" etc/shadow
```

if you have a recent version of GNU awk you can do it with the `-i` like so:

```
awk -i inplace -F: "BEGIN {OFS=FS;} \$1 == \"root\" {\$2=\"$pass\"} 1" etc/shadow
```

Comment: Thank you but it gave "sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to `s'"

Comment: @Survivor is it possible there is `/` character in your hashed password?  If so, you might want to try using a different delimiter, like `s,^root:[^:]\+:,root:$pass:,' to use `,` instead unless of course there are also commas in your hash

Comment: The "awk" one workd but, "gawk" doesn't have "-i" so "awk" and "nawk" don't have it.

Comment: Yes @Eric Renouf, it is possible ! I'm not sure if it can has commas or not.

Comment: @Survivor so are you set with a solution now, or is there something still causing problems?

Comment: Thanks @Eric, almost done, your second command wokes but "-i" is not supported, to redirect the input to a temporary file, copy it to etc/shadow, after that I remove the temp file.

Comment: @Survivor Great, well if this helps feel free to accept the answer, also, for GNU awk I showed an example of how to use `-i inplace` but I think you need GNU awk 4.1 or later for that, the temp file and rename works though!

Comment: Yeah I will do ;-) But I will use (sed  -i -e "s,^root:[^:]\+:,root:$pass:," etc/shadow) which you wrote in comment, I suggest to put it in your answer to make it more visible.

Comment: Ah good just now saw "-i inplace" ! Thak you, and if it was you who voted on my question, thaks again ! But it did not work :-)

Comment: the one with "awk" is ok, the one with "sed" doesn't work with "root::15980:0:99999:7:::" empty password.

Comment: @Survivor I didn't think about that, you could change `\+` to `\*` and that should work again, `+` means 1 or more, `*` means 0 or more

Comment: Yes I know, and I tried it already "\*" and did not work. No worries, I'm using the "awk" solution with temporary file. Thanks.